# Create array of objects at run time using class name in java

Tags: java, object

We all know we can create an object with the help of class name in the string format. Like i have a class name "Test". Using

```
Class.forName("Test").newInstance()
```

We can create the object of that class.

My question is that is there any way to create an array or array list of the objects using class name ?? OR lets suppose we have an object of the class and can with this object we create the array or array list of the that object.

Comment: Did you mean "array of array list" or "array or array list"?

Comment: ArrayList is easy: `new ArrayList<?>()`

Comment: @jon array or array list

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To create an array, you can use [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) and its [`newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29) method:

```
Object array = Array.newInstance(componentType, length);
```

Note that the return type is just `Object` because there's no way of expressing that it returns an array of the right type, other than by making it a generic method... which typically you don't want it to be. (You certainly don't in your case.) Even then it wouldn't cope if you passed in `int.class`.

Sample code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Object array = Array.newInstance(String.class, 10);

        // This would fail if it weren't really a string array
        String[] afterCasting = (String[]) array;
        System.out.println(afterCasting.length);
    }
}
```

For `ArrayList`, there's no such concept really - type erasure means that an `ArrayList` doesn't really know its component type, so you can create *any* `ArrayList`. For example:

```
Object objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();
Object stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

After creation, those two objects are indistinguishable in terms of their types.

Comment: Maybe I get the OP's question wrong, but I interpret it as "I want an array or arraylist of the type I created", so `Object[] array = new Object[length]` would do.

Comment: @Heuster: Well, that creates an `Object[]`, which isn't "an array of the type I created". It's an array which can hold references of the type he created, but that's a different matter.

Comment: @jon "Object array = Array.newInstance(componentType, length);" This give me the object of array but i want to get object of arraylist. There is any way i can get this??

Comment: @WaqasAli: Did you read the end of the answer, which talks about ArrayList? I think you need to read up on type erasure.

Comment: @MvG: That doesn't compile. (I tried.) You can use it in a variable *declaration*, but not as part of instantiation.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html)

```
Object xyz = Array.newInstance(Class.forName(className), 10);
```

It has a method [newInstance(Class, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,int...%29):

> Creates a new array with the specified component type and length. Invoking this method is equivalent to creating an array as follows:

```
 int[] x = {length};
 Array.newInstance(componentType, x);
```

Comment: Array.newInstance return an object not the array of object

Comment: @WaqasAli: It does create an array, but that can't be expressed in the method signature. What would you expect the signature of `Array.newInstance` to be?

Comment: @JonSkeet since Java has covariant types, I guess `Object[]` would be a valid return type.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Nope, not if you pass in `int.class`.